# can guilty be replaced by some other word in the following sentence?

Tags: word-choice

The term "decadent" is often used to describe food that is over-indulgent and rich in flavor; it is usually associated with food that is high in calories and therefore a "**guilty pleasure**."

more context : http://www.ehow.com/facts_7446719_meaning-decadent-food_.html

Can i replace this phrase with ***forbidden pleasure*** or ***illegal pleasure***

Comment: NO, because they are not, in fact, forbidden or illegal.  They can only make one feel guilty... or not.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "guilty pleasure" is a bit counterintuitive.

It could be read as "**guilt-inducing** pleasure", or "[something that brings pleasure but is considered taboo, unadvisable or lowbrow](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/guilty_pleasure), and thereby makes the person (who has experienced the pleasure) feel guilty afterwards."